# Grab all values from an attribute and push into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a div container with an attribute titled "Location". In this location are a selection of countries segregated by a semi colon. I would like to grab each of these values and push them into an array as individual items, rather than one long string with the semi colon.

```
<div class="item-container" location="United States; United Kingdom; France"></div>
```

Once, I have these I would like to sort them, however, the first half is the most important.

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You might be interested in html5 custom data attributes: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var element = document.querySelector('.item-container');
var locations = element.getAttribute('location').split('; '); // ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France"]
locations.sort(); // ["France", "United Kingdom", "United States"]
```

As mentioned, you can rename `location` to `data-location` and the use `element.dataset.location` to access that string (IE 10+).

Comment: Much better than my answer. Could just add the `.sort()` call on the end.

Comment: @RichardDalton I could, but I wanted to highlight the difference between sorted and unsorted array.

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you (and everyone else) for taking the time to response.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `data-` prefix for custom attribute, i.e.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-container" data-location="United States; United Kingdom; France"></div>
```

[**HTML5 Data Attribute**](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/).

**JS:**

```
var div = document.querySelector('[data-location]');
var arr = div.getAttribute('data-location').split(';').sort();
console.log(arr); // [" France", " United Kingdom", "United States"]
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DmbKV/4/)

Comment: An extra parenthesis on the second line is excessive.

Comment: IMO, it makes the code less readable for a developer familiar with chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/3ma9m/

```
var str = $('.item-container').attr('location');
var n = str.split(";");

$.each(n, function (key, value) {
    $('.item-container').append(key + ": " + value + "<br />");
});
```

Comment: Acceptable solution if jQuery is already in use. What about sorting?

Comment: Sheikh Heera's answer is better and includes sorting. For more information on sort(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort